# Encoding a long signal in MATLAB using Huffman encoding

Tags: matlab, recursion, compression, huffman-code

I'm working on lossless data compression in MATLAB. I wish to encode a signal of about 60000 length. Here's my code:

```
function sig = huffman (Y, fs)

%getting array of unique values
Z = unique (Y);

%counting occurences of each element and listing it to a new array
countElY=histc(Y,Z); %# get the count of elements
p = countElY/numel(Y); %getting the probability distribution

[dict,avglen] = huffmandict(Z,p); % Create dictionary.

comp = huffmanenco(Y,dict) % Encode the data.
dsig = huffmandeco(comp, dict) %Decode the data
sound(dsig, fs)
```

Problem is, for a signal of such length, I exceed the 500 recursion limit at MATLAB, and that error occurs while creating the dictionary. I have already tried to break the signal into parts, but that took hell lot of time, and for only a small part of it. Any ideas how to make it work? Apart from extending the recursion limit, which is rather pointless and time consuming?

Comment: How many symbols? The input of `huffmandict` does not depend on the length. Can you provide example input data?

Comment: Like I said, it's a vector of roughly 60000 elements. I think it is pointless to list it here, the values range from -1.27 to 1.1969. It does not? Then why such an exception occurs? Thanks for replying!

Comment: "the values range from -1.27 to 1.1969" - Thus you are using hoffman encoding for non discrete singanls? It is pretty useless in these cases, because there is no relevant gain. What is `numel(Z)`? This is relevant for the complexity of the coding.

Comment: No, the signal is discrete, actually. numel(Y) is a number of elements of vector  Y. And countElY is the number of occurences of each unique symbol. The number of occurences is divided by the total length of Y, and this way we obtain the probability of occurence of a unique symbol. Having this probability we can build a dictionary, what brings us to my problem...

Comment: I understand your code, but how large is `numel(Z)` or `numel(countElY)`? This is the relevant property for the complexity.

Comment: Z contains about 17000 elements

Comment: These are pretty strange parameters to use huffman, never saw an application with that many symbols. Your encoded data including the table will propably be larger than a fixed encoding with length 15 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to determine why you think it's possible to compress the data.  Is the signal smooth?  Is the range limited?  Is the quantization limited?  What makes it compressible will determine how to compress it.

Simply applying Huffman coding to a series of real values will not compress the data, since each of the values appears once, or maybe a few appear twice.  Huffman depends on taking advantage of many occurrences of the same symbol, and a bias in the frequency, where some symbols are much more common than others.

Compressing a waveform would use different approaches.  First would be to convert each sample to as few bits as are significant and that cover the range of inputs.  Second would be to take differences between samples or use more advanced predictors to take advantage of smoothness in the waveform (if it is smooth).  Third would be to find a way to group differences to encode more likely ones in fewer bits.  That last step might use Huffman coding, but only after you've constructed something that Huffman coding can take advantage of.

Comment: You're right, I did do it exactly with this approach. Thank you!